# 90% client error rate in GC Cloud Storage panel

Tags: cloud, store

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFxEb.png)After launching a bucket in GC cloud storage, I still have a very high rate of "client errors" after 3 days. Never seen before.. The bucket has high traffic. Any ideas?

Tried nothing yet, don't know where to start. awaiting ideas from you guys